# "Starting Home Folder" in panel for about 10 seconds in Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, mate, panel, ubuntu-mate, caja

If I start my Home folder it will open as expected but there is this "Starting Home Folder" message in the panel for about 10 seconds until it disappears. I did not find any way how to fix that problem in Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS. I reinstalled Caja and Nautilus but both did not change anything. If I start Caja directly, this problem does not appear.

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

Running `cat ~/.config/mimeapps.list` results in the output:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/discord-455712169795780630=discord-455712169795780630.desktop
text/x-tex=org.kde.kile.desktop
application/x-executable=ktelnetservice5.desktop
application/x-sharedlib=ktelnetservice5.desktop
text/x-haskell=geany.desktop
audio/mpeg=mpv.desktop
audio/x-mpegurl=mpv.desktop
audio/x-scpls=mpv.desktop
audio/x-vorbis+ogg=mpv.desktop
audio/x-wav=mpv.desktop
video/mp4=mpv.desktop
video/mpeg=mpv.desktop
video/mp2t=mpv.desktop
video/msvideo=mpv.desktop
video/quicktime=mpv.desktop
video/webm=mpv.desktop
video/x-avi=mpv.desktop
video/x-flv=mpv.desktop
video/x-matroska=mpv.desktop
video/x-mpeg=mpv.desktop
video/x-ogm+ogg=mpv.desktop
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
text/html=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/about=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop
inode/directory=caja-folder-handler.desktop
text/plain=pluma.desktop
image/bmp=eom.desktop
image/gif=eom.desktop
image/jpeg=eom.desktop
image/png=eom.desktop
image/tiff=eom.desktop
application/pdf=atril.desktop
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/vnd.ms-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop

[Added Associations]
text/x-tex=org.kde.kile.desktop;
*/*=chromium-browser.desktop;
text/x-haskell=geany.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;
text/html=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/about=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/mailto=thunderbird.desktop;
application/x-extension-eml=thunderbird.desktop;
message/rfc822=thunderbird.desktop;
inode/directory=caja-folder-handler.desktop;
text/plain=pluma.desktop;
image/bmp=eom.desktop;
image/gif=eom.desktop;
image/jpeg=eom.desktop;
image/png=eom.desktop;
image/tiff=eom.desktop;
application/pdf=atril.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/msword=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document=libreoffice-writer.desktop;
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.ms-excel=libreoffice-calc.desktop;
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet=libreoffice-calc.desktop;

[Removed Associations]
application/x-executable=ktelnetservice5.desktop;
application/x-sharedlib=ktelnetservice5.desktop;
```

Comment: Can you run `caja` command from terminal?

Comment: @N0rbert Yes I can. Same as with the caja application running ```caja```  from terminal does not cause any issue. Only by clicking the "home folder" application this issue appears. Interesting enough since it seems that running  "home folder" and running caja (from terminal or by clicking the application) lead to the same result which is - the homefolder does open.

Comment: Please add output of `cat ~/.config/mimeapps.list` to the question body (or to pastebin if it is long).

Comment: @N0rbert I added the output as instructed

Comment: The association list looks correct. But exactly how did you "start my Home folder"? From Desktop - by double clicking on "user's Home" or by using some other method? How did you get Home icon on the top MATE Panel (at the right of Thunderbird icon)?

Comment: I just dragged it there from my desktop. I think that icon was on desktop since I installed Ubuntu and I just thought it is more convenient to have it on the panel so I can access my home folder while in other applications. Now I have created a caja shortcut instead which does literally the same but without problems. Some additionally observation: @N0rbert Accessing the homfolder by clicking the corresponding icon on desktop does not cause the mentioned issue but if I drag the icon to the panel it immediately will cause this problem. Very interesting behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this behavior and reported is as [bug 1877734](https://pad.lv/1877734).

The fix is to edit the dragged shortcut and change **Command** field from `caja --no-desktop` to simple `caja`.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The fix works perfect for me!